# How to (Scale/Zoom) Grid.Children (Images) with the Button.Click C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, grid, resize

There is a Grid, which is filled dynamically with Image controls in code behind(Sorry for that).
Grid has 1 column, many pages, each page has 1 Border with Image as Border.Child inside. What I need is to Zoom (Scale) my Image in Grid when Button.Click event fires. I used Scale Transform with the Image before, but I didn't manage to bind Grid element Image with the Click handler.
Please suggest, how I can zoom images inside grid, step by step. 
**Thanks in advance!**

Yes, I know this is horrible, should be done in different way, I'm still learning, how to do this right.

Method, that generates Grid. After that ZOOM click method ( only for zoom, there is another method for zoom out)

```cs
public void RefreshView(List<TiffImage> tiffImageList)
{
    try
    {
        if (tiffImageList.Count == 0)
            return;
        SetControlSizes();
        gridImageList.Children.Clear();
        gridImageList.RowDefinitions.Clear();
        gridImageList.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();

        RowDefinitionCollection rd = gridImageList.RowDefinitions;
        ColumnDefinitionCollection cd = gridImageList.ColumnDefinitions;

        cd.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
        for (int i = 0; i < tiffImageList.Count; i++)
        {
            rd.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        }

        int rowIndex = 0;
        foreach (var tiffImage in tiffImageList)
        {
            Image imageListViewItem = new Image();
            imageListViewItem.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
            RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(imageListViewItem, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
            imageListViewItem.Name = $"Image{tiffImage.index.ToString()}";
            imageListViewItem.Source = tiffImage.image;
            imageListViewItem.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            imageListViewItem.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            imageListViewItem.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
            imageListViewItem.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            imageListViewItem.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

            Border border = new Border();
            border.BorderBrush = Brushes.LightGray;
            border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
            Thickness margin = border.Margin;
            border.Margin = new Thickness(20, 10, 20, 10);
            border.Child = imageListViewItem;
            Grid.SetColumn(border, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(border, rowIndex);


            gridImageList.Children.Add(border);
            rowIndex++;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}


private void btnZoom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (UIElement item in gridImageList.Children)
    {
        Border border = (Border)item;
        Image image = (Image)border.Child;
        var imgViewerScaleTransform = (ScaleTransform)(image.LayoutTransform);
        if ((imgViewerScaleTransform.ScaleX + 0.2) > 3 || (imgViewerScaleTransform.ScaleY + 0.2) > 3)
            return;
        imgViewerScaleTransform.ScaleX += 0.2;
        imgViewerScaleTransform.ScaleY += 0.2;
        image.LayoutTransform = imgViewerScaleTransform;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to scale all images at the same time?

Comment: This will be acceptable. I have long vertical line of Images, which I can scroll Up/Down, so user should be able to Zoom Image/All images. I think the effect will be the same. The format of Image Viewer changed, so I searched, how to zoom grid elements, but I didn't manage to find any solutions. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Not sure what *acceptable* means. What is your actual goal? If a single, selected image should be zoomed, you should use a ListBox (because it supports selection) and only scale the selected image.

Comment: Maybe, my solution should be changed. My goal is to make a vertical collection of Images, which you can scroll up/down from 1st Image to the Last with scrollbar.
I have a button, that should zoom the whole line of Images, so user can scroll the zoomed line of Images. It should work like in Adobe Acrobat(not advertising) when you move scroll bar and PDF pages scroll . Please ask, if you need more details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So why aren't you using a ListBox or perhaps an ItemsControl in a ScrollViewer? And why a Grid when a StackPanel would be a lot simpler? Or a UniformGrid with Columns=1 in case all images should be equally sized.

Comment: Thanks for advice, the problem is, that I don't know, how to scale items inside ListBox, ItemsControl and StackPanel. What I managed to do, is , that I take all Images from Grid, Scale(Zoom) them, then I refill  Grid.Children with new, Scaled Images. It works. Do you think such approach  will work, if we change Images container from Grid to ListBox / ItemsControl / StackPanel ? Thanks!

Comment: I'll write an answer. Are all images supposed to have equal size initially ?

Comment: Well, all images should be pages of some document, so yes, images will contain pages like A4 paper list standard.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple version of a scalable ItemsControl in a ScrollViewer.

It might be improved in many ways. First of all, you should replace handling Button Click events by binding the Button Command properties to ZoomIn and ZoomOut commands in the view model (left out for brevity).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
            <ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Scale}" ScaleY="{Binding Scale}"/>
            </ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray">
                        <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Content=" + " Click="ZoomInButtonClick"/>
        <Button Content=" - " Click="ZoomOutButtonClick"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;

        foreach (string imageFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
            @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures", "*.jpg"))
        {
            viewModel.Images.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageFile)));
        }
    }

    private void ZoomInButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel.Scale *= 1.1;
    }

    private void ZoomOutButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel.Scale /= 1.1;
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> Images { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>();

    private double scale = 1;

    public double Scale
    {
        get { return scale; }
        set
        {
            scale = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Scale)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg, you wrote it so quickly, that's impressive! Thank you so much for your time, it will help me to improve my code)

Comment: Thanks to XAML and MVVM it is actually not much code.

Comment: To know this fact, and to be able to write working code, are two different things. I know, that it will be better, but still I didn't manage to create correct working code using MVVM and all XAML capabilities. So thanks again, your solution really helped me to understand, how this should be done, looks elegant to me. I will take this code and I will try to add rotation of images.

Comment: If it's the same rotation for all images, apply a RotateTransform to the Image's (or the Border's) Render- or LayoutTransform and bind to another view model property by `Angle={Binding DataContext.RotationAngle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}`.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find an ugly, horrible solution, sorry for that. Use it only, if there is no any alternative. Please, add answers with better solutions. Thanks for your time!

We need to add (in code behind) Image.LayoutTransform defined as ScaleTransform:

```cs
imageListViewItem.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform();
```

I used // to emphasize changes in method below. Also, most changes happened in Zoom/ZoomOut methods below.

```cs
public void RefreshView(List<TiffImage> tiffImageList)
{
    try
    {
        if (tiffImageList.Count == 0)
            return;
        SetControlSizes(); 
        gridImageList.Children.Clear();
        gridImageList.RowDefinitions.Clear();
        gridImageList.ColumnDefinitions.Clear(); 

        RowDefinitionCollection rd = gridImageList.RowDefinitions;
        ColumnDefinitionCollection cd = gridImageList.ColumnDefinitions;

        cd.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
        for (int i = 0; i < tiffImageList.Count; i++)
        {
            rd.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
        }

        int rowIndex = 0;
        foreach (var tiffImage in tiffImageList)
        {
            Image imageListViewItem = new Image();
            imageListViewItem.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
            RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(imageListViewItem, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
            imageListViewItem.Name = $"Image{tiffImage.index.ToString()}"; 
            imageListViewItem.Source = tiffImage.image;
            imageListViewItem.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            imageListViewItem.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            imageListViewItem.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
            imageListViewItem.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            imageListViewItem.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            //  Add  HERE!!!
            imageListViewItem.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform();
            //
            Border border = new Border();
            border.BorderBrush = Brushes.LightGray;
            border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
            Thickness margin = border.Margin;
            border.Margin = new Thickness(20, 10, 20, 10);
            border.Child = imageListViewItem;
            Grid.SetColumn(border, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(border, rowIndex);
            gridImageList.Children.Add(border);
            rowIndex++;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

We take all elements from the Grid and Scale(Zoom) them, then we clear the Grid.Children and fill it with new Items.

```cs
private void btnZoom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Border> list = new List<Border>();
    foreach (UIElement item in gridImageList.Children)
    {
        Border border = (Border)item;
        Image image = (Image)border.Child;
        var imgViewerScaleTransform = (ScaleTransform)(image.LayoutTransform);
        imgViewerScaleTransform.CenterX = 0.5;
        imgViewerScaleTransform.CenterY = 0.5;
        if ((imgViewerScaleTransform.ScaleX + 0.2) > 3 || (imgViewerScaleTransform.ScaleY + 0.2) > 3)
            return;
        imgViewerScaleTransform.ScaleX += 0.2;
        imgViewerScaleTransform.ScaleY += 0.2;
        image.LayoutTransform = imgViewerScaleTransform;
        border.Child = image;
        list.Add(border);
    }
    gridImageList.Children.Clear();
    foreach (Border border in list)
    {
        gridImageList.Children.Add(border);
    }
}
private void btnZoomOut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Border> list = new List<Border>();
    foreach (UIElement item in gridImageList.Children)
    {
        Border border = (Border)item;
        Image image = (Image)border.Child;
        var imgViewerScaleTransform = (ScaleTransform)(image.LayoutTransform);
        imgViewerScaleTransform.CenterX = 0.5;
        imgViewerScaleTransform.CenterY = 0.5;
        if ((imgViewerScaleTransform.ScaleX - 0.2) < 0.8 || (imgViewerScaleTransform.ScaleY - 0.2) < 0.8)
            return;
        imgViewerScaleTransform.ScaleX += -0.2;
        imgViewerScaleTransform.ScaleY += -0.2;
        image.LayoutTransform = imgViewerScaleTransform;
        border.Child = image;
        list.Add(border);
    }
    gridImageList.Children.Clear();
    foreach (Border border in list)
    {
        gridImageList.Children.Add(border);
    }
}
```